# Assign fastforward MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c

How can i assign whats going to happen when you press fastforward or rewind?

I have a couple of youtube videos that i want to play after eachother. Therefor i need to assign these 2 buttons in the MPMoviePlayerController. i've tried to search on this subject, but have not found anything yet.

The other thing is how can i check wether a song is done, cause i want it to automatic to go forward then.

[image]

How can i do this?

Comment: Do not seem like it works

Comment: You also tried this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134578/next-previous-buttons-on-iphone-mpmovieplayercontroller