# How do we control next and previous icon in mpmediaplayerviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to do action for next and previous button event for ios video player, here am using mpmovieplayerviewcontroller.

Comment: You can refer here

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134578/next-previous-buttons-on-iphone-mpmovieplayercontroller]

Comment: is that possible to get next and previous button events for MPMediaplayerviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

`MPMoviePlayerController` fires off `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` when either the Prev or Next is tapped. There's no way to be notified whether each one is tapped.

The only way I found, was to create my own custom controls for backward and forward, adding a target to it to perform an action:

```
[prevBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[nextBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in your `onClick` method:

```
 (void)onClick:(UIButton*)sender
 {
     if (sender == prevBtn)
     {
        // Do whatever when prevBtn is tapped
     }
     else if (sender == nextBtn)
     {
        // Do whatever when nextBtn is tapped
     }    
 }
```

FYI: you must set the player's `controlStyle` property to `MPMovieControlStyleNon` to hide the default controls.